# rsync update from FAT32 not working correctly

Tags: rsync

I'm using a FAT32 usb-key to mirror my data from work (linux machine) to home (macOS machine).

I discovered that FAT32 doesnt work well with the --archive option, so I'm using on macOS the command line

```
rsync -vrt --update --modify-window=1 -i /Volumes/usbkey/ /.../mydir/
```

yet rsync insists on re-copying everything all the times, usually with this extended-info:

```
>f..T....... filename
```

... but if I check the dates of the transferred files, they are the same!

Comment: You may need to increase the modify window to 3 because it's being triggered both when you write to the FAT32 filesystem from your Linux-based machine and also when you write from it to the Mac

Comment: It looks like you've shown us the `rsync` command for copying from the USB key to the Mac. What about the command used for copying from the Linux-based system to the USB key?

Comment: roaima: the command I use from Linux to FAT32 is the same. I just add a '--max-size=3999m' to prevent size errors

Comment: @roaima : interesting suggestion about modify-window, since I didnt know about it: the man just talks about 0 and 1 values. I tried it but damn it didnt work...

Comment: man rsync : -
 --modify-window=NUM, -@
When  comparing  two  timestamps,  rsync treats the timestamps as being equal if they differ by no more than the modify-window value.  The default is 0, which matches just integer seconds.  If you specify  a negative  value  (and  the receiver is at least version 3.1.3) then nanoseconds will also be taken into account.

 Specifying 1 is useful for copies to/from MS Windows FAT filesystems, because FAT  represents times with a 2-second resolution (allowing times to differ from the original by up to 1 second).

Answer (score 0):

> ... but if I check the dates of the transferred files, they are the same!

The dates that are normally displayed for files, using a dir listing, are the modification times.

Did you try the `--crtimes, -N` option, so that the creation times get preserved also?
*(This change needs to be propagated to all copies of course before it settles down)*

Comment: no, I didnt know about it - but since the go-between between the two systems is a FAT32 key, do you think that FAT32 can store also creation times? I'll try it in any case...

Comment: If rsync can't set anything it will tell you anyhow :)